# Can I make custom scrollbar binded to some action work using only html/css?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Here I have an image how it have to looks like on the page. But I have to use only html/css. Can you give me some advice, is it even possible? 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YOZA.png)

Thank you.

Comment: I don’t see a scrollbar there. Did you mean the slider? Yes, the design is possible with `border-radius`, `linear-gradient`, `radial-gradient` and `box-shadow` (`inset` and `outset`). Not sure whether the functionality is doable with HTML and CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

That's a slider, not a scrollbar. It's simple with jQuery.

Here's a solution that might work for you, though:

http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/07/creating-a-slider-control-with-the-html5-range-input/

Answer (score 0):

**Input Type range:**
Not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("[type=range]").change(function(){
    var newval=$(this).val();
    $("#slidernumber").text(newval);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" 
name="discount_credits1" id="discount_credits" 
/>
<span id="slidernumber">50</span>
```